# mitmproxy: HTTP request wit nonexsisting leading 0 in data

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying to use mitmproxy to look at the traffic from my win32 schannel tls client. But when I try to use mitmproxy the following messages throw an "Bad HTTP request line" error with a leading 0 in the binary dump that does not exsist in the data that my client sends (I have checked with a little python server).

```
"CONNECT www.example.com:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"

"HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n"

Send Tls Client Hello:
16 03 03 00 AC 01 00 00 A8 03 03 5F 80 1A 2D F6 2A 59 DE 18
69 F0 BB 3C 2D 2B 11 90 F8 8C A7 F9 D7 96 CD DC 32 88 02 22
11 90 6A 00 00 2A C0 2C C0 2B C0 30 C0 2F 00 9F 00 9E C0 24
C0 23 C0 28 C0 27 C0 0A C0 09 C0 14 C0 13 00 9D 00 9C 00 3D
00 3C 00 35 00 2F 00 0A 01 00 00 55 00 00 00 14 00 12 00 00
0F 77 77 77 2E 65 78 61 6D 70 6C 65 2E 63 6F 6D 00 0A 00 08
00 06 00 1D 00 17 00 18 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D 00 1A 00 18
08 04 08 05 08 06 04 01 05 01 02 01 04 03 05 03 02 03 02 02
06 01 06 03 00 23 00 00 00 17 00 00 FF 01 00 01 00

Bad HTTP request line: b"\x00\x16\x03\x03\x00\xac\x01\x00\x00\xa8\x03\x03_\x80\x17\xbd\x1f\xf3\x8fO\xddy\xfb\xaaR\x1c\xeb\xe0sdD\xb7}|\xeb\xbes\xdf$3\xb6\xd9\ry\x00\x00*\xc0,\xc0+\xc00\xc0/\x00\x9f\x00\x9e\xc0$\xc0#\xc0(\xc0'\xc0"
```

Now my question: Is this just a lack of understanding in how proxys and tls work or an error from mitmproxy?

Comment: From my knowledge of the mitmproxy codebase it'd be unlikely that a nonexists null byte appears here. Have you double-checked with WireShark if there may actually be a null byte?

Comment: I just checked in WireShark and there is no null byte in the tls part of the message but in the tcp protocol there is a 16 bit null value corresponding to the tcp urgent pointer which is just in front of the tls part. Could this be where the null comes from?

Comment: We just open a regular socket in Python, so that's unlikely. No Null-Byte if you right click -> "follow" -> "tcp stream" and then select "show data as: hex"?

Comment: Well I am stupid. I just realised that the CONNECT message also sent the null terminator of the string leading to this null byte in the client hello. Thank you for the help.